# Render Latex to png on Python (very light rendering)

Tags: python, latex

I want to render LaTeX with a python program to an image (preferably png but jpg would also work). The content would be really light. For example, the code generated would be one single math problem at most. For example,

```
What is the value of $\frac{(2112-2021)^2}{169}$?

$\textbf{(A) } 7 \qquad\textbf{(B) } 21 \qquad\textbf{(C) } 49 \qquad\textbf{(D) } 64 \qquad\textbf{(E) } 91$ % source: 2021 Fall AMC 12A Problem 1
```

may be what I want to render (obviously may change). **I have stored it formatted in latex in a string, and all I need to do is to convert it to an image.**

I'm trying to do it with pylatex right now (though an answer does not have to be using pylatex), but it is prompting me an error saying that no LaTeX complier is found. (full error below) I should also note that I'm using replit.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylatex/document.py", line 298, in generate_pdf
    raise(CompilerError(
pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found
Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.
```

Comment: I think matplotlib may render latex if you pass it in as a title. That may be part of a solution.

Comment: @PatrickPoitras However I believe that title can only take one line while my text may take more than one line. **I would occasionally need asymptote too.**

Comment: some modules may need external tools/libraries like `GhostScript` or full `LaTeX` and it may need to install it separatelly (because it is not Python module) - and `replit` may not have it.

Comment: @furas Is there a workaround?

Comment: @PatrickPoitras I basically have the same error when I try it with Matplotlib: `RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found`

Comment: sooooo, do you have a latex distributution like texlive or miktex installed?

Comment: I don't think so? I don't actually know how though, specifically on replit. Replit usually have all packages installed and I just have to import them. Do I need to do something like `import texlive`?